# Can't enter text to textfield with input type 'email'

Tags: selenium-ide

I can't seem to enter text into a email type text field. How to enter text to a text field with email type?

Here is the code snippets i got from the page:

```
<input type="email" name="email-123" ng-model="value123" ng-disabled="(v.disable === true)">
```

Here is what I have tried so far and it is not working,

```
 type | xpath=/html/body/div[1]/portal/div/div/tenants/div/div/div[2‌​]/form/div[1]/div/di‌​v/md-content/fieldse‌​t[3]/div[1]/div/div/‌​md-input-container/i‌​nput[@name='email-12‌​3'] | "aaa@yopmail.com"
```

Comment: Can you please provide code snippets of what you have tried so far in selenium, and of the HTML you're interacting with. Without these it's haard to provide any solution

Comment: Here is the code snippets i got from the page:

 <input type="email" name="email-123" ng-model="value123" ng-disabled="(v.disable === true)">

Here is what I have tried so far and it is not working,
type | xpath=/html/body/div[1]/portal/div/div/tenants/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div/md-content/fieldset[3]/div[1]/div/div/md-input-container/input[@name='email-123'] | "aaa@yopmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is try to simplify the xpath, you don't need to start from the very beginning of the page. If the element is unique,

```
//i‌​nput[@name='email-12‌​3']
```

will suffice. It may just be failing to resolve such a long xpath to find the element.

Comment: Well, simplified xpath or not I located the element, there's no problem with that but when I tried 'type' or 'sendKeys' commands with value of email address it doesn't seem to enter the said value.